# Where is "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, visual-studio

When I right click on the references folder in my solution, I see "Add Reference" and "Add Web Reference". I don't see a "Add Service Reference" option.

Whereas in a lot of places on the internet I see people complaining of the opposite - they see "Add Reference" and "Add Service Reference" and they have to go to Service Reference to get to "Web Reference". 
I don't see "Service Reference" option on my install of Visual Studio 2010. And I need it - is this some option/settings I need to set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. My Application was targetting .NET 2.0. Looks like Add Service Reference is not available for .NET 2.0. Once I changed this option to .NET 4.0, this became available.